# Reading single feature as dict into GeoDataFrame with GeoPandas

Tags: python, geometry, geopandas, geodataframe, dictionary

I have a Leaflet map where a user can select a feature and be able to download some data for that feature. I'm getting the object like this to pass to Python:

```py
data = {
  "type": "Feature", 
  "properties": {
     "objectid": 2344, 
     "tnmid": "{552D45C2-D29C-40A7-B277-5F1CCDF1DE14}", 
     "states": "IN,MI", 
     "huc8": "04050001", 
     "name": "St. Joseph", 
     "globalid": "{20353D2E-0ECC-46A2-BCFD-E829FC2E711D}"
   }, 
  "geometry": {
     "type": "Polygon", 
     "coordinates": [[[-85.88886265927873, 42.37182446748738], [-85.88387597280898, 42.37306933617892], ... ]]
}
```

Then I convert it to a `GeoDataFrame`, but I don't think I'm really doing this right since all the properties become rows themselves.

```py
gdf = GeoDataFrame(data)
```

Output:

```sh
            type  ...                                           geometry
objectid     Feature  ...                                                NaN
tnmid        Feature  ...                                                NaN
states       Feature  ...                                                NaN
huc8         Feature  ...                                                NaN
name         Feature  ...                                                NaN
globalid     Feature  ...                                                NaN
type         Feature  ...                                            Polygon
coordinates  Feature  ...  [[[-85.88886265927873, 42.37182446748738], [-8...
```

What I want is something more like this (I don't care about any of the properties of the feature, I just need the geometry in a `df`):

```sh
id     geometry
0      POLYGON (((-85.88886265927873, 42.37182446748738], ... )))
```

I saw `GeoDataFrame.from_features` but that seems to only be for `FeatureCollections`.

Comment: Check this thread : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67499286/python-how-to-convert-a-list-of-dictionary-to-a-geopandas-dataframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the data in a list so it's an iterable and use [`GeoDataFrame.from_features`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.from_features.html):

> Alternate constructor to create GeoDataFrame from an ***iterable of features*** or a feature collection.

Example:

```py
gdf = geopandas.GeoDataFrame.from_features([data])

print(gdf.head())
```

```sh
   geometry  ...                                            globalid
0  POLYGON ((-85.88886265927873, 42.37182446748738...  ...  {20353D2E-0ECC-46A2-BCFD-E829FC2E711D}
```